# Free Font similar in style to verlag

Tags: fonts, typefaces

Was wondering if anyone could suggest a free font that is similar in style to Verlag.

http://idsgn.org/posts/know-your-type-verlag/

Just looking for an experienced eye's opinion for something that matches feel/style.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [Hero](http://fontfabric.com/hero-free-font/) or [Quicksand](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand)?

If not, take a look around above site (fontsquirrel.com) - they usually have a lot of great fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I found a few good ones on fontsquirrel

Comment: @Paul do you recall the specific fonts you found that you liked?